# Securing an OAuth / OpenID Connect identity in a cookie for easy login

Tags: security, cookies, encryption, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have a website that uses Azure Active Directory or Google+ for logging in. I go through an OAuth2 login flow, and the users email along with their tokens are returned to me by their identity service.

The users email address is their identity, and foreign resources (tokens, and other things) are stored using the email address as a foreign key. Right now I'm saving the users email address in a heavily encrypted string, and when the page loads I look for a cookie, decrypt it, and find the email address and open that account.

Is this secure? Is there a good pattern for storing the users Identity?

**GOALS:**

I do not want to force my users to have to login every time they visit the website.

*BUT MORE IMPORTANT*

It needs to be secure.

Answer (score 1):

For the Azure AD part, you could simply use any of our web sign on sample but configure the cookie to be persistent. The cookies produced by the OWIN middleware are signed and encrypted, hence you'd be fine on that side, but that would not protect you from the general issues of session persistence. 
That is NOT recommended as this would carry all sorts of issues - it would be impossible for Azure AD to revoke the token (unless you have server side logic that attempts to redeem a refresh token at every new "session), you'd open up to walk-ins, cookie stealing and lost device attack scenarios, and so on.
The "I do not want to force my users to have to login every time they visit the website" goal can be approximated by leveraging an identity service that is used very often by your users. That maximizes the likelihood that your users are entertaining a session with that identity system at all times - which means that if you configured your web site to do SSO with that identity system, the user will experience smooth sign in even if you did not persist sessions. What you lose is that you won't be mathematically certain that the user does have an active session with the identity system, but you do gain a lot in term of security - e.g. perhaps the user cannot sign in because he/she has been removed from that directory, hence he is no longer supposed to have access.
HTH
V.